# Bug in Kendo DropDownList release 2015.1.318

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

've just tried giving the latest release of Kendo UI a spin, but it seems something has broken when using a DropDownList in a custom popup editor.

If the `dataSource` of the DropDownList is set to a JavaScript array or object, the selected value does not update the Grid model.

DropDownLists that have a remote `dataSource` with `dataTextField` and `dataValueField` configured are working okay.

Basically, code that worked perfectly with the 2014.3.1316 release is not working with the 2015.1.318 release (no errors are reported in Chrome's console).

Can somebody please confirm that this is a bug with the new release, or is there something else I need to be aware of?

EDIT: This is seems to be affecting all DropDownLists. The selected item is not updating the model immediately -- only when the record is saved.

I've knocked together a simple [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPuS8/27/) to demonstrate the issue. With the previous version, selecting an item updates the Grid's model immediately and set's `dirty` to true. With the new version, the Grid's model isn't updated (at least not immediately).

Comment: ...and what is your question?

Comment: Good question! Well, there's no facility to report these issues to Telerik unless you have a professional license, but I believe Telerik staff see stuff on here. So I suppose the question would be... 'Can anyone confirm that this is indeed a bug?'

Comment: Ahh! I guess that makes sense, I reckon you should stick a question in there to prevent the influx of downvoters :-)

Comment: The [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index) from this page seems to work fine. Can you provide a sample of it not working?

Comment: I've edited the question to include a Fiddle demonstrating issue.

Comment: Your fiddle does not work, but I think it is most likely a problem with the custom editor's bindings.

Comment: Fiddle should work now. There's no issue with the bindings. The same code behaves differently when moving to the 2015 Q1 release.

Comment: upvoted because I was banging my head against the wall trying to figure out whether or not I did something to break my code, while re factoring a large amount of javascript. This is a real issue.

Comment: I think https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/623 is the bug? supposedly getting pushed in th enext update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described issue is a known bug in Q1 2015 - [BUG 623](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/623).

It is addressed in the latest internal builds and the upcoming service pack, that will be released till the end of week, will include the fix (and [many more](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed%20milestone%3A2015.Q1.SP.next))

I am afraid that there is no simple workaround, as [the widget just sets its "_old" value to the new one on first select](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/2015.1.318/src/kendo.dropdownlist.js#L371). Hence the change event will not be raised. The only feasible solution is to upgrade to a newer version of Kendo UI.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the dropdownlist and multiselect controls they have changed a lot to allow the new grouping and virtualization features to work. (having been a victim of this change as well - I'm still trying to fix my code at the minute)

I have updated your fiddle with a possible solution for what you want to achieve [Update with Change Event added](http://jsfiddle.net/xLvr8vbt/)

I have basically added this function for you:

```
function changeCategory(e)
{

     $('#log2').text('This should be the ID of the category you changed too: '+ 
e.sender.value());
    }
```

but for more information on this change you can look here: 
[Changes to Kendo UI Q1 2015](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/changes-and-backward-compatibility#kendo-ui-2015-q1)

**EDIT**:
Also if my memory is correct I think the select event is fired before the change event so that will always show the previous value and not the new value that has been selected and when you click update the grid is updating as expected from what I can see.

Comment: I tend to use quite a lot of dependent methods (calculated fields) with the Grid widget -- these no longer work if they rely on the value of the selected item. It's true that the selected value is applied correctly when the record is saved/updated, but this kind of defeats the object of an 'Observable' object if the model is not updated in a timely fashion.

Comment: With this being a new release it may just be a bug and fixed in the next update. I think they have an internal build update scheduled for this week so it may be worth checking that when it is released to see if that corrects this defect.

Comment: Yeah... I'm certainly not going to start adding a load of workarounds at this stage, only to find they are unnecessary in a week or two. I'll stick with the previous version until this is resolved one way or another. Cheers.

Comment: I know that feeling. I have reverted back to the previous version as well until I have some time to resolve the multitude of issues this change has presented with my project. But at least you have a usable workaround if required.

Answer (score 1):

just try to specify a defaultValue in your schema model definition to CategoryID, i think this would be a better solution, couse this bug occurs only when the value is empty

Answer (score 0):

The [Changes to Kendo UI Q1 2015](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/changes-and-backward-compatibility#kendo-ui-2015-q1) page doesn't directly mention the change in behavior described, but it's likely to be caused by the substantial changes to the DropDownList widget.

There's a pretty simple workaround, but I suspect it shouldn't be necessary and will be 'fixed' at some point.

To emulate the old behavior you just need to manually set the model field that's supposed to be updated immediately. So in the `select` event add something like...

```
model.set('CategoryID', dataItem.CategoryID);
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLvr8vbt/4/). Without doing this, any dependent methods will use the original or old value, which is simply not right (hence, I suspect it'll be fixed).

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the problem with dropdown lists with the 2015.1.318 release.
In the latest release, 2015.1.327, this seems to be fixed.

Comment: 2015.1.327 doesn't seem to be available

Comment: I simply used Telerik VS extension, UI for ASP.NET MVC -> Upgrade Wizard and downloaded latest version. It's available there.